# Swift: How to move to next UITextField if the user reach max char

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I'm trying to find a way that when the user reach to the maximum characters the text field move to next.

Here is my code:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        
        guard let text = textField.text else {
            return true
        }
        let length = text.count + string.count - range.length
        let max = 2
        
        if textField == weTextField {
            return length <= max
        }
        else if textField == theyTextField {
            return length <= max
        }
        
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please add additional clarifications to your question to allow us to help you - What is the issue you are running into (what is actually happening compared to what is expected)? What trouble shooting steps have you taken?

Comment: I have two text fields, the user should enter numbers to them (max digits are 2) and now is working fine, if the user entered two numbers the text field delegate will not allow to him to add more. BUT what I want is when the user enter 2 digits (reaches the maximum) it will move to next text field automatically. Thanks

Comment: Do you want it to move back to the first text view if they max out the second text view as well? Or just transition from the first to the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing something like this:

1. create a function that will change your first responder when a character limit is reached

   ```
     @objc func valueDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return }
        let maxLength = 2
        switch textField {
        case textField1 where text.count == maxLength:
            textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        case textField2 where text.count == maxLength:
            textField3.becomeFirstResponder()
        default:
            break
        }
    }
   ```
2. Add that function to your textfield so it's triggered when the textfield is edited.  In the above case, I added it to both textField1 and textField2

   ```
    textField1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    textField2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
   ```

[image]